# error installing module axolotl_curve25519

Tags: python

I'm trying to run project : Yowsup github project

I keep having this error message : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'axolotl_curve25519'`

When I try to install it using : `pip install python-axolotl-curve25519`

I keep having this error messages :

```
C:\Users\Administrateur\Desktop\ws\yowsup-master>pip install python-axolotl-curve25519
Collecting python-axolotl-curve25519
  Using cached python-axolotl-curve25519-0.4.1.post2.tar.gz (79 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: python-axolotl-curve25519
  Building wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      c:\users\administrateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:463: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.4.1-2' to '0.4.1.post2'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'axolotl_curve25519' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve\ed25519
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve\ed25519\additions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve\ed25519\nacl_sha512
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icurve/ed25519/nacl_includes -Icurve/ed25519/additions -Icurve/ed25519 -Ic:\users\administrateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\administrateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include /Tccurve/curve25519-donna.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve/curve25519-donna.obj
      curve25519-donna.c
      curve/curve25519-donna.c(48): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'string.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519
  Running setup.py clean for python-axolotl-curve25519
Failed to build python-axolotl-curve25519
Installing collected packages: python-axolotl-curve25519
  Running setup.py install for python-axolotl-curve25519 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for python-axolotl-curve25519 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      c:\users\administrateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:463: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.4.1-2' to '0.4.1.post2'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running install
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'axolotl_curve25519' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve\ed25519
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve\ed25519\additions
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve\ed25519\nacl_sha512
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Icurve/ed25519/nacl_includes -Icurve/ed25519/additions -Icurve/ed25519 -Ic:\users\administrateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\administrateur\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include /Tccurve/curve25519-donna.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\curve/curve25519-donna.obj
      curve25519-donna.c
      curve/curve25519-donna.c(48): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier includeÿ: 'string.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> python-axolotl-curve25519

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: your visualstudio is lacking some needed packages to compile C code .. Fix would be to install those from within visual studio itself.

Comment: I'm running project from terminal. Should I install visual studio? do you have a link for that ?

Comment: According to the log  you shared, you do have it already installed but it is missing some support packages as strings.h and most like something else is missing. Can't help you further, i dont have VS nor windows machine available to check what you actually would need ..